# R shiny selectInput to update value of a variable in source script, the variable is used to compute the model output plotted by the app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am building a shiny application which visualises the output of a complex model.
The model is in a script which is sourced by the shiny app.
I want to change one input of the model calculation with *selectInput* and plot the output model accordingly.

Below is a simplied version of the model's source script and the app.

**model.R**

```
#data of the model 
yellow_data <- c (10,28,14,40)
green_data <- c(20,40,50,90)
red_data <- c(50,50,50,80)

third_data <- c(30,32,3100,500)

data_model <- data.frame(yellow_data, green_data, red_data)

#the variable that should be updated by selectInput in the app.R
selected_data <- "yellow_data"

#the model output which should change according to changes in selected_data
model_output <- union(data_model[[selected_data]] * 200, third_data)
```

I want to change the value of the variable *selected_data* from the app.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

source("model.R")


ui <- fluidPage(
  
selectInput(inputId = "select_data", label = "SELECT DATA", choices = c("Yellow" = "yellow_data",
                                                                          "Green" = "green_data",
                                                                          "Red" = "red_data")),  
  plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot_model_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot_model_output <- renderPlotly({ 
    
    selected_data_Change <- reactive({
      switch(input$select_data,
             "Yellow" = "yellow_data",
             "Green" = "green_data",
             "Red" = "red_data") 
    })
    
    selected_data <<- selected_data_Change()
       
    fig <- plot_ly(x = ~c(1:8), y = ~model_output, name = 'model output', type = 'scatter', mode ='lines')
   fig
  
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see in **app.R**, I tried to update with *selectInput* the global variable *selected_data* which is used to compute *model_output* in **model.R**, which is sourced in **app.R**.

I would like the *model_output* to update and reflect according to *selectInput*.

I really hope you can help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId = "select_data", label = "SELECT DATA", choices = c("Yellow" = "yellow_data",
                                                                          "Green" = "green_data",
                                                                          "Red" = "red_data")),  
  plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot_model_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot_model_output <- renderPlotly({ 
    
    #the model output which should change according to changes in selected_data
    model_output <- c(data_model[,as.character(input$select_data)]*200, third_data)
    
    fig <- plot_ly(x = ~c(1:8), y = ~model_output, name = 'model output', type = 'scatter', mode ='lines')
    fig
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks, model_output in the real model.R is achieved after many computations and interactions with other data which change its structure. This fix works for this simplified example but in reality, I would need to insert all the computations of model.R in output$plot_model_output of app.R which is not ideal because there are both long scripts. I tried also with inserting the source(model.R) in  output$plot_model_output or with observeEvent but nothing worked. Do you know if there is a way? thank you for your help

Comment: Sure there is a way.  If this MRE is not appropriate, then you need to create a proper [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that you can implement the answer in your real use case.

Comment: I have posted a more detailed MRE here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622945/r-shiny-selectinput-to-update-variable-in-sourced-script 
I hope you can help. Thank you

Comment: @jhonccc, I am not sure I understand the question.  This should work without modifying your other source programs.  You call the model you want from `model.R`.  Please check how `union()` works.  Duplicates are removed, resulting in different length for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks, I think what I am looking for is to wrap the script into a function or a module so that can be called with a reactive. I found this collection of resources which I hope you can find useful beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/2816/Shiny-Modules.html but I am new to the topic and I have not figure it out yet what would be the most efficient way. Any tip is appreciated. thanks